# Why can we extend the derivation of delta(S mix) to ideal solution from ideal gas behavior?

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering

The formula for change in enthalpy for ideal gas is derived using ideal-gas law which cannot be extended to ideal solutions (my intuition). Then why can we extend the formula of delta S mix to ideal solutions from ideal gas.
[image]

Comment: You should provide the source.

Comment: @SolarMike The book which i reffered is introduction to Chemical Engineering thermodynamics by smith and vanness